# References to LOGNS in Microsoft Enterprise Library Code

Tags: enterprise-library

I inherited a small Microsoft Enterprise Library project that supposedly worked a couple of months ago. From what I can tell, it has code that was lifted directly from the Enterprise Library source (?!) instead of linking the built DLLs.

Sigh.

So, there are classes that don't compile in the `Microsoft.Practices.ENterpriseLibrary.*` namespaces. There's a reference to a cryptic `LOGNS` namespace which has a static `LogHelper` class with a bunch of `Log*` methods.

I can't figure anything out about this class, other than that it's missing (and trivial to stub out), but I'm concerned that I may be missing some references (in my GAC?) or something.

This is one trivial error out of several; I have a feeling this code *did* work (since it's ten projects in a solution), and only that I'm missing something locally.

But what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no such namespace or class in Enterprise Library. Sounds like you didn't get all the source code.

Well, no current versions - any idea what version of Entlib you're dealing with?

Comment: I have no idea. I was hoping it would be referenced DLLs, but it looks like it's not.

Comment: is there a way to determine from the source code which version of EntLib it is?